# Tm.plugin.webmining in R - Google News feeds

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to learn text mining in R.

I am encountering problems when it comes to using the tm.plugin.webmining package when trying to mine google news and finance pages (please see codes and error messages attached below).

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Using GoogleNewsSource

```
googlenews <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource("Microsoft"))
Unknown IO errorfailed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=Microsoft&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"
Error: 1: Unknown IO error2: failed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=Microsoft&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"

library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(purrr)

company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook",
             "Twitter", "IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix")
symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "TWTR", "IBM", "YHOO", "NFLX")

download_articles <- function(symbol) {
  WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}

stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company,
                             symbol = symbol) %>%
  mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
failed to load HTTP resource
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 1: failed to load HTTP resource
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Pls Go through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `NASDAQ:TWTR`. Removing both `"Twitter"` from the `company` and `"TWTR"` from the `symbol` resolves the error.

```
company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook", "Netflix")
symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "NFLX")

download_articles <- function(symbol) {
  WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}
stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company,
                             symbol = symbol) %>%
  mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
stock_articles
#     # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     company symbol          corpus
#       <chr>  <chr>          <list>
# 1 Microsoft   MSFT <S3: WebCorpus>
# 2     Apple   AAPL <S3: WebCorpus>
# 3    Google   GOOG <S3: WebCorpus>
# 4    Amazon   AMZN <S3: WebCorpus>
# 5  Facebook     FB <S3: WebCorpus>
# 6   Netflix   NFLX <S3: WebCorpus>
```

Comment: I recommend going to https://www.google.com/finance and search for a specific company of your interest such as "Twitter". Then the search result will bring the correct symbol for you: NYSE:TWTR in this case. @raoul you might want to incorporate that info to your answer.